# How register overloaded template member function in ChaiScript?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, overloading, chaiscript

I have the next definition class:

```
class MyType {
public:
    template <typename T>
    MyType& put(const std::string& s, T&& val);

    template <typename T>
    MyType& put(size_t pos, T&& val);

    template <typename M, typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<MyType, std::decay_t<M>>::value>>
    MyType& put(const M& o, T&& val);
}
```

How is the right way to register overloaded template member functions `MyType::put` in ChaiScript v6.0.0?

I am trying specialized value template (Discussed in: http://discourse.chaiscript.com/t/issues-with-adding-templated-and-or-overloaded-operators/19/3):

```
chai.add(chaiscript::fun(static_cast<MyType& (MyType::*)(const std::string&, uint64_t)>(&MyType::put<uint64_t>), "put");
```

But not compile because there several candidate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
static_cast<MyType& (MyType::*)(const std::string&, uint64_t)>(
    &MyType::put<uint64_t>)
```

But if you look at your first member function, its signature is:

```
template <typename T>
MyType& put(const std::string& s, T&& val);
```

If `T` is `uint64_t`, then the second argument isn't `uint64_t`. It's `uint64_t&&`. Hence, what you want is:

```
static_cast<MyType& (MyType::*)(const std::string&, uint64_t&&)>(
    &MyType::put<uint64_t>)
//                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: @chema989 (1) It's called a forwarding reference. (2) If you pass in an lvalue, you're not calling `put<uint64_t>`, you're calling `put<uint64_t&>`. It's a different instantiation.

Comment: Yeah I have to register each different instantiation in ChaiScript. Thanks @Barry.